# How to debug a java code with getters and setters?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, junit

I was given an empty class and instructed to fill it with instance variables and methods with bodies, which set or get values from the instance variables.  Then I am to open another java file where code creating a new Contact object was provided and instructed to add additional code that uses that object to test all the methods created in the Contact class.

I am using the program Eclipse for coding/testing.  The only things are correct are my method headers. When testing with what I have written (below) I get a null, null response (that is when I remove what wrote about the setPhoneNumber.  When it's included I get a worse looking error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem: phoneNumber cannot be resolved to a variable.)

Any assistance on getting the get/set methods to work will be much appreciated.  *I am entirely new to any programming and have looked at about dozens of examples and have tried many variations with no success.*

```
public class Contact
{
//Instance Variables
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int phoneNumber;

public String getFirstName()  //method to retrieve first name 
    {
        return this.firstName;
    }
public void setFirstName(String firstName)  //method to set the first name
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }
public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
public int getPhoneNumber()
    {
        return this.phoneNumber;
    }
public void setPhoneNumber(int phoneNumber)
    {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
public void call()
    {
    System.out.printf(getFirstName(), getLastName(), getPhoneNumber());
    }
}
```

Here is the other java file used to test the Contact class above:

```
    public class ContactTestDriver
{
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Contact contact = new Contact();  

    //all above was given; below are my code additions
    String myContact;
    myContact = contact.getFirstName();
    contact.setFirstName();
    System.out.println(myContact);

    myContact = contact.getLastName();
    contact.setLastName();
    System.out.println(myContact);

    int myNumber;
    myNumber = contact.getPhoneNumber();
    contact.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    System.out.println(myNumber);

    }
}
```

After some helpful comments I have made changes but still no success.  My error is "myContact cannot be resolved to a variable"

Here is the revised code: 
    public class Contact
    {
    //Instance Variables
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int phoneNumber;

```
public void setFirstName(String firstName)  //method to set the first name
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }   
public String getFirstName()  //method to retrieve first name 
    {
        return this.firstName;
    }
public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }   
public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }
public void setPhoneNumber(int phoneNumber)
    {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
public int getPhoneNumber()
    {
        return this.phoneNumber;
    }

public void call()
    {
    System.out.printf("Who to call ", getFirstName(), getLastName(), getPhoneNumber());
    }
}
```

And this is the code to test the Contact class:

```
public class ContactTestDriver
{
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Contact contact = new Contact();  

    //all above was given; below are my code additions
    String firstName = "a"; //define first name
    contact.setFirstName(firstName);  //then set it
    myContact = contact.getFirstName();  //then get it
    System.out.println(myContact);

    String lastName;
    contact.setLastName(lastName);
    myContact = contact.getLastName();
    System.out.println(myContact);

    int myNumber = 123;
    contact.setPhoneNumber(phonNumber);
    myNumber = contact.getPhoneNumer();
    System.out.println(myNumber);

    }
}
```

Comment: you are trying to pass phoneNumber variable to setPhoneNumber method, but you don't have such variable in main method scope

Comment: Why do you tagged as Javascript? actually it's just Java.

Comment: you getting null for the values set to blank for lastname and fisrtName.also you are setting phoneNumber varible to setPhoneNumber which doesn't exist.

Comment: The code formatting - "the goggles they do nothing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `contact.setFirstName();` which take String parameter you didn't pass the first name

```
public void setFirstName(String firstName){...}
```

and also with `contact.setLastName();` : this also needs to send parameter

like this :

```
String lastName="//last name";
contact.setLastName(lastName);
```

and you need to know that we use the setter method before getter method

so first **set** the names then **get** it

---

```
    String firstName = "a";////define the first name
    contact.setFirstName(firstName); //// then set it 
    myContact = contact.getFirstName(); /// then get it
    System.out.println(myContact);

    String lastName = "b";
    contact.setLastName(lastName);
    myContact = contact.getLastName();
    System.out.println(myContact);

    int myNumber = 123;
    contact.setPhoneNumber(myNumber);
    myNumber = contact.getPhoneNumber();
    System.out.println(myNumber);
```

Comment: This seems like a step forward but now I'm getting "myContact cannot be resolved to a variable" errors - any suggestions?

Comment: '
public class ContactTestDriver
 {
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  Contact contact = new Contact();  
  
  String firstName = "a"; //define first name
  contact.setFirstName(firstName);  //then set it
  myContact = contact.getFirstName();  //then get it
  System.out.println(myContact);
  
  String lastName;
  contact.setLastName(lastName);
  myContact = contact.getLastName();
  System.out.println(myContact);

  int myNumber = 123;
  contact.setPhoneNumber(phonNumber);
  myNumber = contact.getPhoneNumer();
  System.out.println(myNumber);
    
  }
 }'

Comment: you didn't define `myContact` , like this `String myContact` !!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have:

```
myContact = contact.getFirstName();
contact.setFirstName();
```

First you are getting, then you are setting. Reversing them makes more sense:

```
contact.setFirstName();
myContact = contact.getFirstName();
```

Moreover, set methods like setFirstName should receive a String parameter:

```
contact.setFirstName("Johny");
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I have changed the code and added string parameters and now my error message reads "myContact cannot be resolved to a variable" for all methods.  I have added the revised code to the original posting if you care to take a look at it?

Comment: You have to set those in the main class, not inside your getter-setter Class

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eclipse debugging tool.Run you java class in debug mode and add break points where ever you need to analyze data.

Answer (score 0):

getter is just a method getting a  field and setter is setting a new field.
 you must set some values first  i.e

```
int myNumber;
myNumber = contact.getPhoneNumber();
contact.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
System.out.println(myNumber);

int myNumber= "983445556"; // here you are creating an instance
```

or you can do it by

```
 contact.setPhoneNumber(32435435345);
```

similarly for rest cases

Answer (score 0):

Here phoneNumber is not a defined variable in your `main` method

```
int myNumber;
myNumber = contact.getPhoneNumber();
contact.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
```

it should be defined.